# Count the number of changes in a column - Google Script / Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, I ask you to excuse me if I make some language-mistake (I'm Italian!).
I'm trying to write a script for a Google Sheet that can help me to track the number of changes of a column. I would like a counter that grows everytime a value of a cell changes.  Ex:

-Column A: the cell A3 changes from "2020" to "2021"
-Column B: the cell B3 changes from 0 to 1 (o from 2 to 3, a simple +1 on the value).

I wrote this code but I cannot understand where is the error.

```
  function onEdit(e) {
  incrementCounter_(e);
}

function incrementCounter_(e) {
  
  var stw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Foglio2");
  var c1 = stw.getRange(2, 1);
  var c2 = stw.getRange(2, 2);


  if (!e || !e.range) {
    return;
  }
  
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  for (var i=2; i<=6; i++){
  if (sheet.getName() === stw && e.range.getA1Notation() === stw.getrange().getvalue(i,1)) {
   var cell = stw.getrange().getvalue(i,2);
   cell.setValue((Number(cell.getValue()) || 0) + 1);
  }
}
}
```

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: where are you setting "e", what is the value of "e", what is the purpose of "e"? Are you deploying this as an add on? did you create it through google sheets if its not an add on?

Comment: (e) is a traditional name of argument for event-driven functions, means 'event'. Some event. When spreadsheet is changing it generates the event-object. The function 'onEdit' can read this object, its properties, and do something if the properties fit to some conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There is no need to use two functions for this.*

#### Code

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName(); 
  if (sheetName == "Foglio2" && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var val = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
   sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(val + 1);
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

What you want can be achieved by using the `onEdit(e)` trigger. The above function makes use of the `e` event object and checks where exactly the edit is being made. As it can be seen, the `for` loop is not needed in this situation as in order to get the column and row needed the `getColumn()` and `getRow()` methods have been used.

In this situation, the script checks if the sheet in which the edit has been made is `Foglio2` and if an edit has been made on the `A` column. If the condition checks, it increments the corresponding value from the `B` column.

#### Note

Please note that `getValue(value1, value2)` is not a valid method and if you want to get the value for that specific range, you must pass the two parameters to the `getRange()` method.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet);
- [Apps Script Range Class - getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).

Comment: Thank u very mutch!! It was exactly what I was looking for!! :) I'm sorry but actually i'm not very familiar with javascript and i'm trying to learn js for my job. You were very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A3') {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B3');
    var value = range.getValue();
    value++;
    range.setValue(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, did you want to change a couple of cells in any row (a3-b3, a4-b4, a5-b5... etc)? Not just the row 3?